# Easier way to style error message part of all vaadin components

Tags: vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I want to change the default style for all vaadin components which has errorMessage part. The only way i know is to use @CssImport(value="...", themeFor="...") annotation for each vaadin component I want to style. Is there any other easier, nicer ways to do it?

The reason why i want to do this:
I want to increase the *max-height* css property from *5rem to 10rem* (I wish i could edit this with a global css variable to any value) and add *word-break: break-word* property too, because some error message overflows both horizontaly and verticaly.

[image with example of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNXy5.png)

[image with example of my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQFzx.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar approach would be to use the theming where you create a vaadin-text-field.css, vaadin-combo-box.css and so on inside your theme/your-theme-name/components/ folder. Those files are automatically added to the components making it s little bit easier to maintain (subjective). See more details in Vaadin documentation about [Creating Custom Theme](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/customization/custom-theme).

Comment: Is it possible to use @import in these theme/components/ css files, if yes then I'll stick to your solution. I don't know if this issue is going to cause a problem for me: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/9794

Comment: In the long run / if you use vite instead of we pack as suggested by Artur

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support older browsers like IE11 and pre-Chromium Edge, you can do that easily for all Vaadin components with the `::part()` selector in a global stylesheet:

```
::part(error-message) {
  max-height: 10em;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```